# Squid no more max_user_ip?

Tags: squid

I'm compiling latest squid (3.4) and I noticed it's complaining about my (working) rules regarding `max_user_ip`:

`acl concurrent_browsing max_user_ip -s 5`

I checked the [configs](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/) and it seems it disappeared completely? Is there any replacement for this?

Answer (score 1):

**Maximum logins per user**

Squid provides an ACL type max_user_ip, which is matched when a single username is used for authentication from more than a specified number of machines. A directive authenticate_ip_ttl is used to determine the timeout for the IP address entries. So, if we want our clients to log in from, no more than, three different machines, we can use the following configuration:

```
acl ip_limit max_user_ip 3
http_access deny ip_limit
```

The default behavior is to deny random requests once the limit is reached. We can deny
complete access by specifying the option -s while constructing an ACL.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in 3.4 if you add the `-s` directive it crashes squid so I filed a bug report following this.